# Qliksense data load editor script aggregation syntax?

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to do a simple aggregation in the Qliksense data load editor. However, this results in an error. Is there a particular Qlik syntax to follow to achieve this?

```
Load
"var_1",
"var_2",
"var_3",
"agg"

SQL select "var_1", "var_2", "var_3", sum(var_4) as "agg"
from table
groupby "var_1", "var_2", "var_3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be `;` between Qlik's `Load` statement and the `SQL` statement

```sql
Load
"var_1",
"var_2",
"var_3",
"agg"
; // <-- separate Qlik script and SQL
SQL select "var_1", "var_2", "var_3", sum(var_4) as "agg"
from table
groupby "var_1", "var_2", "var_3"
```